# A video comes up as blank

Tags: mac, video, vuze

I downloaded a video but when I press the play button in Vuze, the window comes out but after a bit of wait the movie does not play (the stop/pause button is grayed at the same time, no play button on the window)

Also another thing I noticed while playing a video that DID play, was that I didn't know how to fast forward or backward. When I play a video through quicktime I just press the corresponding buttons on F7-F10, but it does not work for Vuze player.

Comment: Does that particular movie play properly in either QuickTime or VLC?

Comment: So you downloaded a pirated movie (which may very well be a fake) via torrent from the interwebs and now you'd expect us to help you out? You got to be kidding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/) to play the video.